# React Native + lib-jitsi-meet - audio/video tracks not getting added to the conference

Tags: jitsi, video-conferencing, jitsi-meet

We are trying to create a React Native mobile app for Jitsi from scratch using the lib-jitsi-meet API, and we have a self-hosted jitsi-meet on AWS server and we followed [quick-install guide](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart). For the purpose of this post, the URL is `https://jitsimeet.example.com`.

In the React Native app, we are able to join a conference called `test1` using `JitsiMeetJS.initJitsiConference`. Once joined, the user is visible as "Fellow Jitster" on the browser at `jitsimeet.example.com/test1`, **but the tracks (video/audio) we are adding to the conference (from React Native mobile app) are not visible and in the browser, it just says "Participant has stopped the camera" and "Participant is muted"**.

We have tried `meet.jit.si` & `beta.meet.jit.si` in our React Native app to see if the problem is related to our backend installation. But these were also not working.

We have also tried the same conference `jitsimeet.example.com/test1` on the browser and in jitsi-meet mobile app and they are both working fine without any issues.

We have also set up the [jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet) repository locally. On running the React Native part on the Android emulator, it is working fine (both joining the conference and rendering the audio/video tracks).

From the above observations, it seems to be that the issue is coming from our implementation of React Native app.

Our code for the component that initiates the conference can be found [here](https://github.com/s-xync/rn-jitsi-poc/blob/master/screens/ClassScreen/ClassScreen.js). Here you can find the link to [our repository](https://github.com/s-xync/rn-jitsi-poc). To run it, just do `npm i` and `npx react-native run-android`. We are using polyfills in our react-native code as given in the [jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet) repository.

In the logs of jicofo on our server, we were able to see that when users join via web or jitsi-meet mobile app, we are getting:

```
org.jitsi.jicofo.ParticipantChannelAllocator.log() Sending session-initiate to: test1@conference.jitsimeet.example.com/2502e6ad
org.jitsi.jicofo.JitsiMeetConferenceImpl.log() Got session-accept from: test1@conference.jitsimeet.example.com/2502e6ad
org.jitsi.jicofo.JitsiMeetConferenceImpl.log() Received session-accept from test1@conference.jitsimeet.example.com/2502e6ad with accepted sources:Sources{ video: [ssrc=467278592 ssrc=2301072636 ssrc=839807103 ssrc=3616291734 ssrc=2331517151 ssrc=3181098946 ] audio: [ssrc=2795704819 ] }@2129717334
```

Whereas when we join via our React Native app, we are only getting:

```
org.jitsi.jicofo.ParticipantChannelAllocator.log() Sending session-initiate to: test1@conference.jitsimeet.example.com/946022e6
```

More information which might be relevant

On the client side, we are adding tracks after `CONFERENCE_JOINED` event is fired, then, we are getting the following logs

```
[JitsiConference.js] _doReplaceTrack - no JVB JingleSession
[JitsiConference.js] _doReplaceTrack - no P2P JingleSession
```

As mentioned above, we can join the conference from our react native app and we are getting `CONFERENCE_JOINED`, `USER_JOINED`, `USER_LEFT` events.

The `TRACK_ADDED` event is also firing locally right after adding local tracks. But it is not firing for any video/desktop-sharing/audio changes occurring on other remote clients (web browser or jitsi-meet mobile app).

How can we fix this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?